# Inserting data to MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose and SRV connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have created a cluster in MongoDB Atlas and can't seem to be able to write data to it.

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://myUser:myPass@myDB-4myav.mongodb.net/portfolio";
```

I have this as my uri to connect to, and every time I try to write to the database, I get this error:

> { MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { insert:
>   "users", documents: [[{name Daniel} {_id
>   ObjectIdHex("5aa6d7d6396deb25844ccb52")} {__v 0}]], ordered: false }

I have read that I need to create an admin user with the role of "root" but when I connect to my database using the mongo shell and try creating it, I get this:

> Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command

So basically I don't have a user that can write to my database.

I've also tried making a user with every role possible on the MongoDB Atlas website (for my cluster of course) and then connecting through the mongo shell with it, but that failed as well.

To summarize: I've made a new cluster on MongoDB Atlas. How do I write data to it?

Thanks in advance, feel free to point out if I'm missing something simple and stupid.

Comment: You need to manage users via Atlas (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/) and create a user account with the "Read and write to any database" role (or more refined privileges with the Advanced Options).

Comment: I've done that. Even better, I've made an account with every possible role as well and I still get denied.

Comment: Ah! The error indicates your code is trying to insert documents into the `admin` database, which is a system database reserved for user and role information. In your connection string you intended to use `portfolio`, but the `srv` connection string does not support specifying a database so you need to change to this database after connecting. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6106 for a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> { MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [[{name Daniel} {_id ObjectIdHex("5aa6d7d6396deb25844ccb52")} {__v 0}]], ordered: false }

This error indicates your code is trying to insert documents into the `admin` database, which is a system database reserved for user and role information.

In your connection string you intended to use the `portfolio` database. However, the `srv` connection string format does not support specifying a database so your option was ignored and the default database of `admin` was used. You need to select the `portfolio` database after connecting.

This was also reported in the Mongoose issue tracker ([GitHub issue #6106](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6106)) where a user posted a workaround you could adapt:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    // Hack the database back to the right one, because when using mongodb+srv as protocol.
    if (mongoose.connection.client.s.url.startsWith('mongodb+srv')) {
        mongoose.connection.db = mongoose.connection.client.db('portfolio');
    }
    console.log('Connection to MongoDB established.')
});
mongoose.connect(...);
```

> I have read that I need to create an admin user with the role of "root" but when I connect to my database using the mongo shell and try creating it, I get this:

You need to [manage users via MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users) rather than the `mongo` shell. You can create a user account with the "Read and write to any database" role (or more refined privileges using Advanced Options).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The workaround was something I wasn't aware of and couldn't find it for the life of me. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a user with **root** role from Mongo Shell,

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
   user: "admin",
   pwd: "password",
   roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
}
);
exit;
```

or you need to add new user through atlas(refer below snapshot)

1. Goto **Clusters**
2. click **Security**
3. Click **ADD NEW USER**
4. type **username**
5. create **Password** based on SCRAM-SHA1 method
6. choose ROLE **Atlas admin**
7. click **Add User**

[image: AddNew-USER]

After created user, goto **Clusters**-->**OverView** -->  **CONNECT**

1. Verify the IP Whitelist
2. Choose a connection method:

   - Connect with Mongo Shell  (I am choosing)
   - Connect your Application
   - Connect with MongoDB Compass

> $ mongo "mongodb+srv://project-u-s3cgp.azure.mongodb.net/test" --username dbAdmin

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.1

Enter password:

connecting to: mongodb+srv://project-u-s3cgp.azure.mongodb.net/test

.........
.........

MongoDB Enterprise project-U-shard-0:PRIMARY>db.user.insert({name:"Daniel"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise O2Ci-U-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

I hope, you can able to insert the record after creation of **root** user.

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: Apparently my code was trying to write to the "admin" database which doesn't work so the nice man on top explained it's a common issue with a neat workaround for it. Thank you for your help nonetheless!